# php cannot load pecl http extension

Tags: php, apache, http, plesk, pecl

I have installed pecl_http on a PLESK server (which seems to be successful) but for some reason, the http extension will not load into PHP.

```
var_dump(extension_loaded("http"));
```

gives me bool(false).

`pecl info pecl_http` gives me a lot of info and if I run `php -me` http is also listed.

php -i | grep "http_request" gives me:

```
http_request => N/A => 0 => 0
http_request_datashare => GLOBAL => 1 => 0
http_request_pool => N/A  => 0 => 0
```

and if I run `pecl run-tests -p pecl_http` I get a lot of FAILs

and I am also getting

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get()
```

http.so is located inside /usr/lib/php/modules/ which is also defined as the extension dir in php.ini - all other extensions loads fine.

What have I missed?

Comment: Which Plesk, OS and PHP version have you installed on your server?

Comment: OS is Linux 2.6.32-042stab072.10, PLESK is 10.4.4 Update #47 and PHP is 5.3.21

Comment: and what is your linux distro name and version?

Comment: I have build pecl_http and add extension=http.so in /etc/php.d/http.ini. And it looks like everything fine php -r 'var_dump(extension_loaded("http"));' returns bool(true). Does this file exists on your server ls -la /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1642342 Mar  1 08:39 /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so ? (lib64 - because i have Centos 5.9 x64 )

Comment: What happens if change enable_dl = Off to enable_dl = On in php.ini and run php -r "dl('http.so');" ?

Comment: Wee... Made it work! Thanks for the help! Will you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if change

```
enable_dl = Off
```

to

```
enable_dl = On
```

in php.ini and run

```
php -r "dl('http.so');"
```

?

Comment: I have this exact problem on CentOS, followed all the instructions above and php -r "dl('http.so');" returns this PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode in Unknow
n on line 0

Also, php -me does not have http included.

Comment: Your issue is not related to this question. Is php-json package is installed on server?(rpm -qa | grep -e php.*json)