# php http extension installed properly but never works

Tags: php, http

What I want to do is to use php to make http request, so that I install http extension and it seems successful, because if I run phpinfo(), I can http extension clearly.

But the issue here is that the http function never works, even for the simplest one.

For example, if I tried the following two scenarios:

1. echo 1;
   echo http_request(HTTP_METH_GET,"http://www.google.com");

I will got "1" as return.

2. echo http_request(HTTP_METH_GET,"http://www.google.com");
   echo 1;

I didn't get anything.

Can anyone help me with it? I have spent too much time on it. - Thanks very much.

Comment: Please turn on your error reporting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) temporarily so we can see what the error says, or find your error_log (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) location and find the error. You might also try the curl functionality, or fopen (assuming you have permissions to open URLs with it?)?

Comment: @Hans It's quite weired though. - Just I posted here, it seems that http_request is an "infinite loop" because "echo 1" never execute in the second case. But for the first case, I can get "echo 1".

Comment: @Hans After I add "error_reporting" in the php code, I didn't see any report yet. Do I need to go to somewhere else in the file system to get to report? Thanks

Comment: <?php

try{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo http_request(HTTP_METH_GET,"http://www.google.com");

if (extension_loaded ('http') == TRUE){
        echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
 ?>

Comment: @Hans Above is my code and it didn't print anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether there is a **http.so** file in your php extension library
usually it locates at /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-no-zts-.

If there it is, add a **php.ini** file in /etc/

and a line 
extension=http.so

I think there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make some changes in your php.ini file

Change `enable_dl = Off` to `enable_dl = On`

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061813/php-cannot-load-pecl-http-extension) too

Answer (score 0):

May be you have installed version 2.* of pecl_http
that is very defferent from and incompatible with version 1.*.

p.s. you can check version in phpinfo() output